# Interview - What made you to move from Development to Automation testing?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, manager

I have a total of 3 yrs of experience, 2 years in development and 1 year in Automation testing. Recently I have attended an interview with one MNC company. In the managerial round, the manager asked me a question(`Why you moved from development to automation &` `What made you to move from Development to Automation testing?). I said I like QA rather than hardcore development`. I knew my answer is not in the impressive way.. What is the best way to answer such a question? And, how could I impress the person by the way of my answer?

Comment: Why not tell the truth about why you made the change?

Comment: It would really help if you told us what made you move. Is "I like QA rather than hardcore development" the true answer?

Comment: @Carson - No, I agree

Comment: A phrase like "hard-core development" gives me a negative impression here. Do you consider QA an easy job in comparison? If I hire you, are you going to treat the job like it's no big deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interviewers ask about career decisions like this because they want to know what makes you tick. When you move from one type of work to another, there's usually a compelling reason and what that reason is will say a lot about you. The best reason to give is something like:

> I found that QA was a better match for my strengths and interests than development.

This is a good reason and allows for a good answer **because you should be able to articulate why QA is a better fit for you**. That shows motivation for the type of work and should convince the interviewer that you made the choice with some deliberation and aren't jumping at the first job they throw at you.

A related reason would be that a previous company needed someone in the QA role and you picked it up on the side or made the transition **and liked it so much that you decide to stay in that role.** The proximate cause for your switch is then that the role needed to be filled, which isn't a great reason. But the ultimate cause is that you enjoyed the work and excelled at it, which is a great reason.

Any other reason such as "*I needed a job*" or "*The money was better*" is a terrible reason to give and you shouldn't ever mention that, even if it's true. **What the interviewer wants to hear from you is that you're excited about working in QA and that that will remain the case for the near-future** (at least 2 years).

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to answer such a question?

The best way is to be honest about your reasons behind your career change.

Spend some time before the interview thinking it over. Remember back before you were in Test Automation, and write some notes about why you left Development and why you landed in Test Automation.

> And, how could I impress the person by the way of my answer?

You can impress an interviewer by showing that you understand your motivations. Rather than saying "I like QA more", you want to talk about *why*. Talk about what it is that you like about it, how it fits your personality and skills. Talk about what makes you particularly good at it. Show some insight.

The try to tie all that into the job for which you are applying.

(And don't use the term "Automation Testing", unless your job is testing automation. If you are crafting the scripts to automate testing, then the term is "Test Automation" or sometimes "Automated Testing".)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to answer such a question? And, how could I
>   impress the person by the way of my answer?

Unless and until the reason is controversial, you should always tell the truth.

**Why?**

Because, interviewers most often then not, can infer from the interview whether you are lying or not. And a lie would be more lethal than a bad reason in that case. In some cases, you might also get some brownie points for an honest reason, even though it might not be an ideal job-landing one.